# Reading from local storage using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, html

How do I read all the values ?  Key is 'Task' and value is following.

```
{"Assignments":[{"AssignedBy":"537000","AssignedBy_FirstName":" JOHN","AssignedBy_LastName":"WANDER"},
{"AssignedBy":"537000","AssignedBy_FirstName":" JOHN","AssignedBy_LastName":"WANDER"}],

"Comments":[{"CommentBy":"537000","CommentBy_FirstName":"JOHN"},  {"CommentBy":"537000","CommentBy_FirstName":" JOHN"}],

"Result":"SUCCESS",

"Tasks":[{"ACT_ARR":"05/20/2013 05:59:00 PM","ACT_DPT":"","ARR_FLT":"0434/20","ARR_GATE":"25"}],

"TasksCurrentStatus":[],

"Updated":"05/30/2013 02:54:09 PM"}
```

I tried ....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var alltask = localStorage.getItem('Task'); 
    var single = alltask.getJSON('Assignments');     
    var acnum = '';
    var obj = $.parseJSON(single);
    $.each(obj, function(i, val){
    acnum += val.AssignedBy + " ";
    });     
        alert(acnum);
    });
```

but the result was:

> Can not find Assignments

Looks like I am not reading the JSON tag correctly

Comment: What errors are you encountering?

Comment: "Can not find Assignments". Looks like I am not reading the json tag correctly.

Comment: so u tried plugging a derivation of a variable into another variable, parsing that derived result variable into a variable, doing an each loop of the parsed variable and adding to another empty variable, and then alerting the result. i doubt breaking it out into steps and testing each step could possibly help.

Comment: We need more information about what `localStorage` is, and what the method getItem('Task'); is doing, I guess. I mean, I'd say you should change `getItem('Task')` to `getItem('Tasks')` since there is no 'Task' anywhere in that JSON. But then, there are no `Assignments` inside of `Tasks` either.

Comment: Task is the "key" for the whole obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `localStorage.getItem('Task')` already returns you the String, no need to ask for `getJSON`, just parse it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var alltask = localStorage.getItem('Task'); 
  //var single = alltask.getJSON('Assignments');     
  var acnum = '';
  var obj = $.parseJSON(alltask).Assignments; // or var obj = $.parseJSON(alltask)["Assignments"]
  $.each(obj, function(i, val){
    acnum += val.AssignedBy + " ";
  });     
  alert(acnum);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it. It still says "Canot read property 'Assignments' of null

Comment: Can you see what `localStorage.getItem('Task')` returns? does it return the string or [object Object]?

Comment: Just created http://jsfiddle.net/CsYLA/ and appears to work just fine. First I set the localstorage (you may do it someplace else) and then the code I suggestes.

Comment: Oh, so I need to JSON.stringify(). Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: Well, assuming you have saved it to localStorage with `JSON.stringify(object_to_save)`, you can recover the whole object with `var obj = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('Task'));`. From there you can get assignments with `var assignments = obj.Assignments`.

Answer (score 0):

It likely has to do with the way you put the data in to be able to get it out as well. For me, when I store my data I typically use `JSON.stringify()` and when I get it out I use `$.parseJSON()`. Here is a little sample (using sessionStorage, but it works the same):

```
var setVals = {
    authorized: $auth.is(":checked"),
    maxOrderAmount: $max.val(),
};

if (window.sessionStorage) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("originalValues", JSON.stringify(setVals));
}

var getVals = $.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem("originalValues"));
```

Without using `stringify` an object was stored, and when I tried to get it all I got was [Object object], so I am not sure that sessionStorage can handle an object literal, and I would imagine localStorage performs basically the same (with the only difference being scope).